# Solve the system $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^k c_i^2=14,\ \sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^k d_i^2=14,\ \sum_{i=1}^k a_i b_i=7$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations

Let $n$, $m$, $k$ be strictly positive integers and consider strictly positive real numbers, $a_i$, $b_i$, $c_i$ and $d_i$. I would like to solve the following system
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^k c_i^2=14\\
\sum_{i=1}^m b_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^k d_i^2=14\\
\sum_{i=1}^k a_i b_i=7
\end{matrix}\right.$$
but, given the variability of $n$, $m$, and $k$, I think the solutions could be infinite. The first question is: is the system as complicated as it seems, or am I not able to find the solutions?

If the answer to the previous question is "yes, the system is really difficult, " I have another question: do you think there is at least one approach to finding some of the solutions to this system in closed form?

Comment: I guess that you assume $k\leq m$ and $k \leq n$.

Comment: You can look at particular solutions, e.g., like taking $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i^2=7$ with all $f_i=\sqrt{7}/n$ etc.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Who Is $f_i$?

Comment: You can chose $f_i$ as some of your $a_i,b_ic_i,d_i$, according to $k,m$ and $n$, so that it matches your equations. For example, in the first equation you'll get $7+7=14$.